# Request validation, how to show errors?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have a form that allows the user to upload 3 files.

Here is the Controller function called :

```
public function registerUpdate(CardAvsRequest $request){
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $first_name = User::find($id)->student->first_name;
        $last_name = User::find($id)->student->last_name;
        $name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
        $message = "";
        if ($request->hasFile('carte-id'))
        {
            $image1 = $request->file('carte-id');
            if($image1->isValid())
            {
                if ($request->hasFile('avs'))
                {
                    $image2 = $request->file('avs');

                    if($image2->isValid())
                    {
                        if ($request->hasFile('permit'))
                        {
                            $image3 = $request->file('permit');

                            if($image3->isValid())
                            {
                                $path = config('card.path')."/$id";
                                $name = "carte-id.".$image1->getClientOriginalExtension();
                                $image1->move($path, $name);
                                $path = config('card.path')."/$id";
                                $name = "avs.".$image2->getClientOriginalExtension();
                                $image2->move($path, $name);
                                $path = config('card.path')."/$id";
                                $name = "permit.".$image3->getClientOriginalExtension();
                                $image3->move($path, $name);
                                $message = "Super ! Vous avez importé tous les fichiers nécessaires.";
                                //ici on dit dans la DB que l'utilisateur à uploadé tous les fichiers
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return redirect()->route('account', $id)->with('message', $message);
    }
```

So the Validation rules are set in CardAvsRequest.php :

```
class CardAvsRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'carte-id' => 'mimes:jpg,png,pdf,gif,jpeg,tiff,doc,docx,odt|max:10000',
            'avs' => 'mimes:jpg,png,pdf,gif,jpeg,tiff,doc,docx,odt|max:10000',
            'permit' => 'mimes:jpg,png,pdf,gif,jpeg,tiff,doc,docx,odt|max:10000',
        ];
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to display errors if a file isn't validated.

Isn't it supposed to work like this ?

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how [Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#manually-creating-validators) documentation suggestion to validate input and return error if any. The view looking good and will display error if occurred.

```
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
     $rule = 'required|file|mimes:jpg,png,pdf,gif,jpeg,tiff,doc,docx,odt|max:10000';

      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
          'file_one'   => $rule,
          'file_two'   => $rule,
          'file_three' => $rule,
      ]);

      if ($validator->fails()) {
          return redirect('account')
                     ->withErrors($validator)
                     ->withInput();
      }

     // no errors proceed managing your files

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but in that case you have to remember that you have to put that code:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

In form file.